# XPath with Timezone

Tags: java, xpath, dst, saxon, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to find the System Date in local timezone using XPath but it always returns me the date in Zulu time. Just to highlight, I'm using Saxon for xPath 2.0.

XPath : fn:current-dateTime()
Result: 2015-02-18T11:21:12.393Z

Is there any way that we can let the XPath know what time zone I'm looking for by passing any argument or something!? I agree that there are XPath 2.0 functions available(fn:adjust-dateTime-to-timezone) for the timezone conversion but will it take care of Daylight saving time?

Thanks

Comment: Saxon picks up the current timezone from the operating system, via Java. What platform are you running (Java or .NET? Operating system?)

Comment: Thanks for the response Kay. It's java running on RHEL.

Comment: I just executed date command and it resulted me the date in GMT! As you said, Saxon seems to be picking up the Operating system's timezone.
user@host: date
Thu Feb 19 08:55:35 GMT 2015

Comment: If you want to set a different date/time/timezone for a transformation, the Controller class has a method setDateTime(). In 9.5 and earlier you can get the Controller by casting the JAXP Transformer; in 9.6 you can get it via a method on the Transformer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Saxon documentation for `current-dateTime`](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.8/functions.html#fn:current-dateTime):

> ... Changed in 7.8 to return a date/time in the local timezone.

Update to a newer version of Saxon.

Comment: I'm running Saxon-HE-9.5.1-6. Not sure why it didn't return in local timezone !?

Comment: Maybe a regression? You should probably log it [in their issue tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/bugs/)